# Defining and handling specific Na values for a function R

Tags: r

I'm currently in the process of writing a function in R. Apart of which I will be needing to define certain character's as NA.

Starting from the beginning

```
file <- readLines("/Users/debraragland/file.txt")
relines <- gsub("\\Frame.+$|\\Chain.+$|\\ATOM-WISE.+$", "", file)
```

Which leaves "" and " ". If I do each step at the prompt, I have to define and omit these as NAs twice

```
relines[relines==""] <- NA
relines <-na.omit(relines)

relines[relines==" "] <- NA
relines <- na.omit(relines)
```

Is there any way I can combine these into one, possible into an if statement?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do what you want:

```
relines[relines == "" | relines == " "] <- NA
relines <- na.omit(relines[!(relines == "" | relines == " ")])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
relines <- relines[relines != "" | relines != " "]
```

Comment: The `|` should be `&`.